# How to Create a New Dataframe from Missing Values Between Two Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

`df1`

```
  Person     Date Company Name Symbol   ID
0   Dale  2019 Q4       A Corp    AAA   10
1   Bill  2019 Q4       B Corp    NaN   20
2   Hank  2019 Q4       C Corp    NaN   30
3  Rusty  2019 Q4       C Corp    CCC   30
4  Peggy  2019 Q4       X Corp    NaN  100
5   John  2019 Q4       Y Corp    NaN  200
6   Kahn  2019 Q4       Z Corp    NaN  300
7   Mihn  2019 Q4       Z Corp    NaN  300
```

`df2`

```
  Company Name Symbol  ID
0       A Corp    AAA  10
1       B Corp    BBB  20
2       C Corp    CCC  30
3       D Corp    DDD  40
4       E Corp    EEE  50
5       F Corp    FFF  60
6       G Corp    GGG  70
7       H Corp    HHH  80
8       I Corp    III  90
```

And I want to create a new `df3` which is made up of `IDs` that are in `df1`, but not in `df2`,so that the output would look like:

`df3`

```
  Company Name Symbol  ID
1       X Corp        100
2       Y Corp        200
3       Z Corp        300
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index based on `'ID'` of both dataframes

```
df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```